# Researching this product: Paderno World Cuisine A4982799 Tri-Blade Plastic Spiral Vegetable Slicer

Tags: us2508868

I am researching this product (Tri-Blade Plastic Spiral Vegetable Slicer) in which the company Paderno World Cuisine claims a patent.  I found no patent for this so far.

The item, sold on Amazon ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0007Y9WHQ/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007Y9WHQ))
is made from plastic and is replicated under many brands.

I've been searching through these patents and so far have not found the patent they claim.  Can a more experienced patient specialist help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! Does the item or packaging have a patent number printed on it?

Comment: The patent linked via the tag expired 30+ years ago and should not be printed on any products any longer.

Comment: Thanks George, I actually received an email from the Company CEO and he provided these patents; utility patent -https://www.google.com/patents/CN202723661U?cl=en&dq=utility+patent+is+201220380804.5&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_W7gUuCYL7SqsASc9oC4CQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA

Comment: There only patent I see mentioned in your question is US2508868. You can get to it by the link under "Helpful links". It has long since expired.